# Is it possible to remember a network but manually initiate connection every time?

Tags: wi-fi

I occasionally use my phone to connect to the work network for quick diagnostic purposes. I do not like being connected to it for regular use, as I don't like my phone activity to be traceable by my employer.

Is it possible to remember a WiFi network, but only connect when manually triggered?

Comment: I would say, the simplest solution is to turn off your wifi when you don't use it as it saves battery and you wont be connected to the wifi, thus simplest solution. Same question has been asked before: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35332/disable-a-specific-wifi-network-from-automatically-connecting-to-in-android?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, but as Matt said, the best thing to do is just to **turn off your Wi-Fi.** There are apps that you can download that will be able to automatically turn off Wi-Fi at your workplace. However, I personally keep my Wi-Fi off at all times, regardless of whether or not I am home. Wi-Fi, despite what most battery saving apps will tell you, consumes *more* power than cellular when you are not using it heavily. For streaming and updating apps, I connect to Wi-Fi, but that is about it.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't like my phone activity to be traceable by my employer.

Perhaps, you should consider VPN.

Anyhow, there are measures you can take here, all of them would require the help of [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) apps, such as [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (paid; 7 day free trial) or [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) (free/paid).

(**Note** that [AutomateIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage) (free/[Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AutomateItPro.mainPackage)) may also be able to achieve the following examples.)

For example:

- If your quick diagnosis always runs or requires an active screen (i.e. no screen off) then you can make Tasker or MacroDroid wait for X minutes and then disconnect or disable the Wi-Fi.
- If your quick diagnosis always requires or ends up after X minutes, use Tasker or MacroDroid to configure your Wi-Fi to disconnect or get disabled.
- Because Android is all about apps, your quick diagnosis probably involves the usage of an app. In that case, use Tasker or MacroDroid to enable the Wi-Fi if only the diagnostic app gets active on the screen and disconnect/disable the Wi-Fi either after X minutes and/or once the app closes.
- If the device is rooted, you can use [AFWall+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall&hl=en) in [combination with Tasker](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/124554/96277) to switch to a firewall profile which would effectively bar all the app (excluding the diagnostic apps) from using internet when  connected to a particular Wi-Fi. Optionally, create a persistent notification. In this fashion, you would always know that you're connected to workplace Wi-Fi.
- Any scenario that suits you would probably fit under the scope of Tasker or MacroDroid.

### Relevant triggers and actions

### Tasker

Triggers:

- Applications → App
- State → Net → Wifi Connected
- State → Display → Display State

Actions:

- Net → WiFi → On/Off
- Net → WiFi Net → Disconnect
- Task → Wait
- Plugin → AFWall+
- Alert → Notify
- Alert → Notify Cancel

### MacroDroid

Triggers:

- Wifi State Change → Connect to Network
- Screen On/Off → Screen Off
- Application Launched/Closed

Actions:

- Wifi Configure
- Display Notification (not persistent)
- Wait Before Next Action